# What does "return {}" statement mean in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, return, return-value, list-initialization

What does the statement

```
return {};
```

in C++11 indicate, and when to use it instead of (say)

```
return NULL;
```

or

```
return nullptr;
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

`return {};` indicates "return an object of the function's return type initialized with an empty [list-initializer](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization)". The exact behaviour depends on the returned object's type.

From [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization) (because the OP is tagged C++11, I excluded the rules in C++14 and C++17; refer to the link for further details):

> - If the braced-init-list is empty and T is a class type with a default constructor, value-initialization is performed.
> - Otherwise, if T is an aggregate type, aggregate initialization is performed.
> - Otherwise, if T is a specialization of std::initializer_list, the T object is direct-initialized or copy-initialized, depending on context, from the braced-init-list.
> - Otherwise, the constructors of T are considered, in two phases:
>
>   - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type std::initializer_list
>   - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).
> - Otherwise (if T is not a class type), if the braced-init-list has only one element and either T isn't a reference type or is a reference type that is compatible with the type of the element, T is direct-initialized (in direct-list-initialization) or copy-initialized (in copy-list-initialization), except that narrowing conversions are not allowed.
> - Otherwise, if T is a reference type that isn't compatible with the type of the element. (this fails if the reference is a non-const lvalue reference)
> - Otherwise, if the braced-init-list has no elements, T is value-initialized.

Before C++11, for a function returning a `std::string`, you would have written:

```
std::string get_string() {
    return std::string();
}
```

Using the brace syntax in C++11, you don't need to repeat the type:

```
std::string get_string() {
    return {}; // an empty string is returned
}
```

`return NULL` and `return nullptr` should be used when the function returns a pointer type:

```
any_type* get_pointer() {
    return nullptr;
}
```

However, `NULL` is deprecated since C++11 because it is just an alias to an integer value (0), while `nullptr` is a real pointer type:

```
int get_int() {
    return NULL; // will compile, NULL is an integer
}

int get_int() {
    return nullptr; // error: nullptr is not an integer
}
```

Answer (score 96):

This is probably confusing:

```
int foo()
{
  return {};   // honestly, just return 0 - it's clearer
}
```

This is probably not:

```
SomeObjectWithADefaultConstructor foo()
{
  return {};
  // equivalent to return SomeObjectWithADefaultConstructor {};
}
```

Comment: So, it is a compile-time error if the return type does not have a default constructor, correct ?

Comment: @KarimPedia it certainly should be.

Comment: It's a compile error if the return type is a class that does not have a _non-explicit_ default constructor and is not an aggregate.

Comment: If the type has an `initializer_list` constructor, wouldn't that be used if no default constructor is available?

Comment: @Oktalist I don't think the *non-explicit* is in play here.

Comment: @celtschk: Luckily, no. Don't give them ideas! An unnamed pair of parentheses or braces creates a nameless temporary value-initialized to whatever the "zero" value is according to the default constructor. An initializer list is created in combination with `auto` and at least one argument. Except... if you are using a compiler that implements N3922, in that case the fun begins, because then it matters for single-value braces whether there's a `=` or not... a very, very ingenious idea to make it different in every case.

Comment: @celtschk Yes, it will. List-initialization is a fairly tricky area.

Comment: "probably confusing" ? Is this why some unnamed soul referred to "That bloated obscenity that is C++"? Can whatever saving in keystrokes this provides possibly justify the potential for lack of clarity it offers?  This is a sincere question. Please convince me with practical examples.

Comment: @mickeyf Using `{}` instead of `0` doesn't save any keystrokes.

Comment: I would prefer `return {};` in the `int` case

Comment: `return {}` is NOT equivalent to `return SomeObjectWithADefaultConstructor{};`

Comment: @mickeyf In all honesty, I think `return {}` is pretty clear, once you get used to it.  It's pretty easy to read it as "See the return type?  It's default-constructible, so return one of those."  ...Of course, if it's _not_ default-constructible, that's when the _fun_ begins.

Comment: @mickeyf in all honesty, I agree with you. syntax shortcuts can be fun and newbies find them impressive, but they are horrid to debug and maintain. I have learned to appreciate pedantic old programmers who spell everything out explicitly.

Answer (score 35):

`return {};` means that `{}` is the initializer for the *return value*.  The return value is list-initialized with an empty list.

---

Here is some background on the *return value*, based on [stmt.return] in the C++ Standard:

For a function that returns by value (i.e. the return type is not a reference and not `void`), there is a temporary object called the *return value*. This object is created by the `return` statement, and its initializers depend on what was in the return statement.

The return value  survives until the end of the full-expression in the code that called the function; if it has class type, then its destructor will run unless it has lifetime extended by the caller binding a reference directly to it.

The return value can be initialized in two different ways:

- `return some_expression;` - the return value is [copy-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) from `some_expression`
- `return { possibly_empty_list };` - the return value is 
  [list-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list%20initialization) from the list.

---

Assuming `T` is the function's return type, then note that `return T{};` is different to `return {}`: in the former, a temporary `T{}` is created, and then the *return value* is copy-initialized from that temporary.

This will fail to compile if `T` has no accessible copy/move-constructor, but `return {};` will succeed even if those constructors are not present.  Accordingly, `return T{};` may show side-effects of the copy-constructor etc., although this is a copy elision context so it may not.

---

Here's a brief recap of *list-initialization* in C++14 (N4140 [dcl.init.list]/3), where the initializer is an empty list:

- If `T` is an aggregate, then each member is initialized from its *brace-or-equal-initializer* if it had one, otherwise as if by `{}`  (so apply these steps recursively).
- If `T` is a class type with a user-provided default constructor, that constructor is called.
- If `T` is a class type with an implicitly-defined, or `= default`ed default constructor, the object is [zero-initialized](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/zero_initialization) and then the default constructor is called.
- If `T` is a `std::initializer_list`, the return value is an empty such list.
- Otherwise (i.e. `T` is a non-class type -- return types cannot be arrays), the return value is zero-initialized.

Comment: Aggregate init comes first, and it recursively initializes every member with `{}`, which may or may not be value-init.

Comment: @T.C. right, I went by cppreference but overlooked an "until C++14"

Answer (score 3):

It's a sort of short hand for a new instance of the methods return type.