# Template function deducing return type

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, return-type, function-templates

I am trying to create a simple template function which takes a callable object and a couple of int values as parameters to that callable, and returns the result of invoking the callable with those values.

**How do I get the function to figure out the return value's type, and also be able to create such a type with its default value?**

This works:

```
template <typename Func>
auto CallFunc(Func f, int a, int b) -> std::invoke_result_t<Func, int, int>
{
    using return_type = std::invoke_result_t<Func, int, int>;

    if (a > 0) {
        return (f)(a, b);
    }

    return return_type{};
}
```

See [here](https://godbolt.org/z/Y7W66nYeq) for a demo.

---

It does feel a little ugly though, and having to deduce it twice like that isn't great.

**Is there a simpler way to achieve this?**

Despite this code working I can't help but feel as though I've taken a wrong turn somewhere!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a simpler way to achieve this?

Simply use [`decltype`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/decltype) here

```
template <typename Func>
auto CallFunc(Func f, int a, int b) -> decltype(f(a, b))
//                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^   
{
    using return_type = decltype(f(a, b));
    //                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

    // ... code    
    return return_type{};
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I also figured out that I don't need the using return_type nonsense either and can just return {}. Nicer!

Comment: @WalderFrey `return {}` doesn't work if the return type would have been void

Answer (score 1):

Since your type must be default constructable, (`return return_type{}`), it will be sufficient just to do this:

```
template <typename Func>
auto CallFunc(Func&& f, int a, int b) -> std::invoke_result_t<Func, int, int>
{
    if (a > 0) {
        return std::forward<Func>(f)(a, b);
    }

    return {};
}
```

[What does "return {}" statement mean in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39487065/what-does-return-statement-mean-in-c11)

(The std::forward is a little bonus advice to be able to use functors that cannot be copied)